# How to reorganize a polynomial including exponents to the simplest form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, expression

I want to reorganize a polynomial including exponents as the following Figure 1 to the form showing as Figure 2. Failed to realize it after several times trying such as Figure 3. Can you help me to get the result? Thank you.

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

[image]

or

[image]

Figure 3

[image]

Here are the codes:

```
In[12]:= Solve[-1 + d - d E^-az + f[z]/f0 == 0, f[z]]

Out[12]= {{f[z] -> -E^-az (-d - E^az + d E^az) f0}}

In[13]:= -E^-az (-d - E^az + d E^az) f0 // Simplify

Out[13]= f0 + d (-1 + E^-az) f0

In[14]:= FactorTerms[-E^-az (-d - E^az + d E^az) f0, f0]

Out[14]= f0 - d f0 + d E^-az f0

In[16]:= Factor[-E^-az (-d - E^az + d E^az) f0]

Out[16]= -E^-az (-d - E^az + d E^az) f0
```

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code,not the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Collect`

```
Solve[-1 + d - d E^-az + f[z]/f0 == 0, f[z]] //Collect[#, {f0, Exp[z_]}] &
(*{{f[z] -> (1 - d + d E^-az) f0}}*)
```

Comment: Include `Simplify` to factor out `d`, i.e., `Solve[-1 + d - d E^-az + f[z]/f0 == 0, f[z]][[1]] // Simplify // Collect[#, f0] &`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, perfect solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
Solve[-1 + d - d E^-az + f[z]/f0 == 0, f[z]] // 
 Simplify[#,
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] +Count[#, _Symbol, Infinity]&)
  ]&
(*  {{f[z] -> (1 + d*(-1 + E^(-az)))*f0}}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.